# Send input value using POST method using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, post, get

I'm trying to send two input values through POST method using Angular.js, but I'm unable to pass these values on URL, or even catch them on the server side.
Could someone help me to solve this?

For each button I need to pass the two values + the button value (operacao)

**Form**

```
<form id="form" ng-controller="Controller">
  <input id="val1" name="val1" ng-model="val1" placeholder="Valor 1" type="text">
  <input id="val2" name="val2" ng-model="val2" placeholder="Valor 2" type="text">
  <input id="operacao" name="operacao" type="hidden" value="0">
  <input id="soma" type="button" value="soma" ng-click="doClick(val1, val2)">
  <input id="sub" type="button" value="sub">
  <input id="mult" type="button" value="mult">
  <input id="divs" type="button" value="divs">
  <input id="resultado" type="text">
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
.controller("Controller", function($scope, operacaoService) { 
  $scope.model = {};
  $scope.doClick = function(operacao) {
    $scope.model.operacao = operacao;
    operacaoService.postOperacao($scope.model)
    .success(function(data, status) {
      $scope.valores = data.result;
        console.log(data.result);
    })
    .error(function(data, status) {
      console.log("erro", status);
    });
  };
})
```

**Service**

```
module.factory('operacaoService', function($http) {

  var postOperacao = function(model) {
    return $http({
      url: "/operacoes",
      method: "post",
      params: model
    });
  };

  return {
    postOperacao: postOperacao
  };
});
```

---

**Server (Node.js)**

```
app.post('/operacoes', function(req, res) {

  var valores = req.query;
  var val1 = parseInt(valores.val1);
  var val2 = parseInt(valores.val2);
  var operacao = (valores.operacao);
  var result;

  if (operacao === "soma") {
    result = val1 + val2;
    res.send({
      result: result,
      val1: val1,
      val2: val2,
      operacao: operacao
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage it looks like you are using the wrong property of the configuration object to set your data payload. The params property is for **GET** requests.

In your service, try editing the $http call as follows:

```
module.factory('operacaoService', function($http) {

  var postOperacao = function(model) {
  return $http({
    url: "/operacoes",
    method: "post",
    data: model
    });
  };

  return {
    postOperacao: postOperacao
  };
});
```

Also, on your server side it looks like you're using express. Instead of using

```
var valores = req.query
```

change it to:

```
var valores = req.body
```

See http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body for more information